# Qmap aspect ratio

Tags: r, ggplot2, qmap

If I map

```
# install.packages("ggmap")
library(ggmap)
qmap("USA", zoom = 4)
```

I get a map of the US, but it but a bit of Maine and a bit of the west coast cut out.  It also extends between the artic circle and Honduras.

Is there a way with qmap or ggmap to change the aspect ratio of the map so that only the lower 48 are shown?  That is specify the x & y limits

Comment: You need to provide more than 18 characters of code...

Comment: @nrussell actually, just adding `library(ggmap)` makes this question reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be a start:

```
library(ggmap)

ggmap(get_map("USA", zoom = 4)) +
  coord_fixed(ylim = c(20, 50), ratio = 5/4)
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on Jason's answer ...

After some [digging](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/kahle-wickham.pdf) I discovered that my problem was with GoogleMap.  While `ggmap` will accept a bounding box, GoogleMap doesn't use it.  The problem I had with the code above was that bits of Maine and bits of the West Coast were cut off.  Maine not so much an issue but NW CA is for my project.

Stamen maps are better at defining boundaries

```
us = c(-125,24,-65,50)
ggmap(get_map(location=us,maptype="toner-background",zoom=4,source="stamen"))
# FOR US ONLY - does not work outside us (more or less)
ggmap(get_map(location=us,maptype="terrain",zoom=5,source="stamen"))
```

Hopefully, Google API will allow bounding boxes shortly